# Code Execution in class or oops

Tags: php, profiling

Suppose I have multiple classes. I have to find out which class code is taking more time to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called profiling. There are many tools out there, open source as well as commercial.

IDEs like Eclipse also have some tooling built in. The best commercial tool I've come across is Wily- now CA Wily